# Find where two git repositories forked without git history

Tags: git, github

Im looking to find exactly where these two repositories forked so that I can see what changes have been made to the original code.

https://github.com/apache/cassandra

https://github.com/wlloyd/eiger

There is no git history for the second one.    I've already determined its not a fork of any of the releases. There are some files such as CHANGES.txt that (Im pretty sure) haven't been modified since the fork, maybe this helps. Perhaps there is a clever diff trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without history, it's nearly impossible to find when the fork has been made.

However, if you're just interested in the changes between the two code bases (ie: the fork, and the current `master` of the original repo) you can do something like:

- clone both repos locally (I assume they're cloned from the same local directory)
- run `diff -r cassandra eiger | grep -v .git` (maybe you can start with `diff -rq cassandra eiger | grep -v .git` to have an idea of the files impacted)

---

Now, if you want to have a rough idea about when the fork has been made, you could try to find the commit in the original repo, which minimizes the number of diff. You could try something like:

```
cd cassandra
for SHA_1 in $(git rev-list master); do
  git checkout $SHA_1
  pushd ..
  echo -n $SHA_1\; >> diffs.csv
  diff -r cassandra eiger | grep -v .git | wc -l >> diffs.csv
  popd
done
```

Now you just need to find the line which minimises the second column